# Angular JS: How to fetch data together collectively over one ajax call?

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Use case: I have comment sections like Facebook, associated with items (e.g. photos). Pages contain multiple comment sections. I'm fetching the comments from an API after the page is loaded. The API works like:

```
/api/comments?forItem=3
```

Every comment section is a directive/web component that I reuse and they fetch their data separately over different ajax calls as expected. I want to make them fetch the data together through one $http/ajax call.

So I made the API work with multiple items for efficiency, i.e.:

```
/api/comments?formItem=1,2,3
```

Major problems I have:

- When to start fetching? How can I know all the loaded Angular directives?a
- How to pass the data into directives?

Or is there a better solution for this use case?

Here's the Javascript Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Seregwethrin/nDq2r/27/

---

When I use the directive multiple times, this is what happens. It makes a call for every directive, and I want to combine those calls in a single ajax request.

[image]

My directive code already works but has the problem I described above.

```
app.directive('commentGroup', function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            id: '='
        },
        templateUrl: '/NgDirectives/CommentGroup.html',
        controller: function ($scope, $http) {
            $scope.comments = [];
            $http.get('/services/get-comment?id=' + $scope.id)
                  .then(function(data) { $scope.comments = data; });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: suggest you create a demo in plunker that gives an idea how your directives work. Seems unorthodox the way you describe it. Can set up several different json files in plunker for the requests. Woud also help to post code here

Comment: How about now? I'm pretty sure this is a common problem there's a good solution.

Comment: reason for demo request is it seems strange to need to make a call for each directive. Why can't you make one call and filter responses? No need to provide console image...anyone who works with angular understands ajax requests

Comment: I didn't provide the console image because you don't know ajax requests. I provided it to demonstrate the problem with visuals. My Angular knowledge is limited but as far as I know the filters are not enough. I need a mechanism to accumulate the ajax request IDs, and then do the request when all IDs are collected, and distribute the returned data back to the directives by the collected IDs. I can write that, but I'm searching for a best practice here. Maybe it is already implemented, some library, maybe a simpler approach.

Comment: goes back to ... **create a demo**. Maybe you just need to make multiple requests. Without some indication of how app works though is impossible to help

Comment: What about this? http://jsfiddle.net/Seregwethrin/nDq2r/27/

Answer (score 0):

I would create a factory that you inject into a directive, where the factory utilizes $http to go and get your data - I am going to edit the answer soon to address the other issue(s) you have, this shows how to inject service into directive to use data from the Ajax request

You might want to look into $evalAsync [http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope) which can function like a setTimeout until the initial digest has finished.

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <my-directive>{{data}}</my-directive>
</div>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.factory('myData', function ($http) {
    return {
        getDataAsync: function (callback) {
            $http.get('/someUrl').success(callback);
        }
    }
});

app.directive('myDirective', ['$compile', 'myData', function ($compile, myData) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.data = myData.getDataAsync(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            });
        }
    }
}]);

app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {});
```

working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/whiteb0x/yBn66/

Comment: This is already what I do, but if I use <my-directive> multiple times it makes a call for every directive. I want to collect the IDs and make the call collectively as /someUrl?getItems=1,2,3,4,5 and then distribute that data for directive-1 directive-2 directive-3 etc.

Comment: ok let me work on solution to that - at least I'm off to a good start ;)

Comment: You really don't need to provide the full code, I just want to know the best practice to do that :) I'm pretty sure other people needed this too!